Python Centering Mouse X Y Coordinates To Operator
I am trying to get familiar with the modal operators in blender and want to create some kind of custom trackball rotation.
When I set the rotation euler values to the mouse_x and mouse_y event values, blender adds the absolute mouse position to the rotation values.
Is there a possibility to start with 0 when I click the operator button?
def execute(self, context):
    bpy.data.objects["Cube"].rotation_euler[0] = math.radians(self.value_z)
    bpy.data.objects["Cube"].rotation_euler[2] = math.radians(self.value_x)
    return {'FINISHED'}

def modal(self, context, event):
    
    if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':  # Apply
        self.value_x = event.mouse_region_x
        self.value_z = event.mouse_region_y
        self.execute(context)


Just store the last ones and subtract them. See: Text Editor > Templates > Python > Operator Modal View 3D

Thank you it worked :)
